# received json data correctly outside of subscribe method from observable

Tags: angular

have this function for extract the user module assigned, this function in the response extract the json of the user module.

```
  getUserModuleInstalled(): Observable<any[]> {
    const userId = this.user.id;
    return this._moduleService.getUserModule(userId).pipe(
      switchMap((response: any) => {
        return from(response.user_module || []).pipe(
          concatMap((userModule: any) => {
            const moduleId = userModule.module_id;
            console.log('User module Id response=> '+moduleId);
            return this._moduleService.getSubscriptionModule(moduleId).pipe(
              map(subModule =>  subModule.data.subscription_modules),
              catchError(error => {
                console.error(error);
                return of(null);
              })
            );
          }),
          toArray(),
          catchError(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return of([]);
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

then a use this function to get return json
and using this json here in ngOninit with this subscribe methods

```
this.getUserModuleInstalled().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    if (data) {
        const new_plans = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log('New plans data:', new_plans);
        new_plans.forEach((plan: ModulesSub) => {
          return this.plansSubject.next(plan);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No data received');
    }
}, (error: any) => {
    // handle the error
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

this.plansSubject.subscribe((plan: ModulesSub) => {
    this.plans = [plan];
    console.log('Plans data:', this.plans);
});
```

//I make a console log for check return this object and is correct
[image]

based on that response , I need to use subscribe as follows since that is the way the *ngFor correctly calls me, example of what the response should be like

```
 this.plans= [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "POS Coffe Shop",
      "price": "5",
      "type": "1",
      "description": "module for sale , managed inventory, ia asistanace",
      "frequency": "month"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "POS Coffe Shop",
      "price": "5",
      "type": "1",
      "description": "module for sale , managed inventory, ia asistanace",
      "frequency": "month"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I need to be able to have a response outside of subscribe, in json like this "this.plans= [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "POS Coffee Shop",
      "price": "5",
      "type": "1",
      "description": "module for sale , managed inventory, ia assistance",
      "frequency": "month"
    }
  ]", the response I am getting is an array like in the photo, how could I achieve this?, thanks

Comment: Could you please create the Stackblitz URL, add your code, and share it? I will assist you with better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should simply you approach. You should follow more reactive approach by using [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe and also simplify you `getUserModuleInstalled()` method and then you can use RXJs [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) and Array's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to be get desired result. You don't need additional subject here.

Update your function like this:

```
getUserModuleInstalled() {
const userId = this.user.id;
const userModule$ = this._moduleService.getUserModule(userId)
return userModule$
    .pipe(
        map((response : any) => response.userModule.module_id),
        concatMap((moduleId: String) => {
          return this._moduleService.getSubscriptionModule(moduleId).pipe(
              map((subModule: any) => {
                return subModule.map(data => data[0]); // You can update your logic as per your requirement here
              })
          );
        })
    );
}
```

Now when you calls above method:

```
const plans$ = getUserModuleInstalled();
```

You can directly use `plans$` with `*ngFor`. Something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let plan of plans$ | async>...</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the array method [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#try_it) to flatten the data and show the output in the `*ngFor`

```
this.getUserModuleInstalled().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    if (data) {
        const new_plans = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).flat(); // <- changed here!
        console.log('New plans data:', new_plans);
        return this.plansSubject.next(plan);
    } else {
        console.log('No data received');
    }
}, (error: any) => {
    // handle the error
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

this.plansSubject.subscribe((plan: ModulesSub) => {
    this.plans = [plan];
    console.log('Plans data:', this.plans);
});
```